# Grid layout not working correctly

Tags: android

I am using android studio 2.3.2 and my problem is that when i add gridlayout to my application i am not able to change the number of columns and rows also there is a message saying that this grid layout is useless also i am not able to add any image to the image view of the gridlayout.I have already tried adding rows and columns using properties in design view and also in text view using xml but it is not working, also i can not see any grid lines when i drag the imageview over gridlayout.

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

use the android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout from the support lib to manage grid layouts in android.

an small preview below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:background="@drawable/bg_paper"
app:rowCount="4"
app:columnCount="3"
app:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_columnSpan="2"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_rowWeight="5"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_onboarding_search" />
<TextView
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:text="@string/onboarding_title_step_1"/>

<TextView
    app:layout_row="2"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_rowWeight="5"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:text="@string/onboarding_message_step_1"/></android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```